# Match MSVC symbol export names to Qt Creator import lookups

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, linker, dllexport

I have a library which I'm compiling in MSVC2012 to be dynamically linked against. Each declaration is preceded by `__declspec(dllexport)` via a macro `LIBAPI`. This builds fine and creates a dll + a lib which symbols such as `_funcname` (from examining with dumpbin.exe).

Over in Qt Creator (backed by same MSVC toolchain) I include the same headers used to build the library but an extra define that changes the `LIBAPI` macro to `__declspec(dllimport)`. Here is where I'm getting linker errors because it is looking for `__imp_funcname`. If I redefine `LIBAPI` to nothing the linker will instead look for `funcname` (no preceding underscore).

I've verified everything else in the compile link toolchain is working correctly, only issue is this function decorator mismatch.

Question then is: how can I either force a convention when building the library (preferably to export the `__imp_` style) or force Qt to find the single underscore symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that I had initiated the project with the x64 version of Qt Creator, so it was using the x64 toolchain to do the compiling and linking. Making a brand new project from Qt Creator x86 add copying all files across sorted everything out